# Python tkinter image label randomly displays some images but not others

Tags: python, image, url, tkinter

I have this code:

```
for imgTag in outputS:
    print(imgTag["src"])

root = tk.Tk()

for imgTag in outputS:
    url = imgTag["src"]
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
        raw_data = u.read()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    image.im = image
    label = tk.Label(root, image=image)
    label.pack( side = tk.BOTTOM)

root.mainloop()
```

It produces this in the command line:

```
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/92913.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/320898.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/6962.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/351124.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/239668.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/375038.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/201969.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/441.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/2384.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/363428.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/1828.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/226478.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/4966.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/375018.png
http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/17484.png
```

However some images display in the tkinter window and some do not. With every list of png links I have there doesn't seem to be a discerable pattern to which get rendered and which don't, although for each list the same ones always get rendered. For example: list1 = [1,2,3,4,5], list 2 = [1,2,3,4,5]. List 1 will always render images 1,3,4 and list 2 will always render 2,3.

In another python file I have:

```
for x in range(0, num_horses):
    row1 = tk.Frame(root)
    row1.pack(side = tk.TOP)

    label = tk.Label(row1, text="horse " + str(x + 1))
    label.pack(side = tk.LEFT)

    imgTag = outputS[x]
    url = imgTag["src"]
    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
        raw_data = u.read()
    im = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    image = ImageTk.PhotoImage(im)
    image.im = image
    label = tk.Label(row1, image=image)
    label.pack( side = tk.LEFT)

    b1 = tk.Button(row1, text="back", command = lambda x=x: backHorse(x + 1))
    b1.pack( side = tk.LEFT )

    b2 = tk.Button(row1, text="lay", command = lambda x=x: layHorse(x + 1))
    b2.pack( side = tk.LEFT )
```

When this is run on the same list of links as the first python they produce different results in terms of which images they render, but they are always the same for the app. For example: on the list [1,2,3,4,5], first code snippet I showed in this post always displays images 1,2,4 and second code always displays images 2,5

Comment: what have you done to debug this? Have you verified the size of the data is greater than zero? Have you tried saving the data to disk to verify that the image data can be opened by anything at all?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably there is some problem with `garbage collector` which probably removes `PhotoImage` so you have to assign to variable.

But not

```
image.im = image
```

It makes no sense.

You need

```
label.im = image
```

Full version which works for me

```
import tkinter as tk
import urllib.request
from PIL import Image, ImageTk
from io import BytesIO

data = [
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/92913.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/320898.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/6962.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/351124.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/239668.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/375038.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/201969.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/441.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/2384.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/363428.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/1828.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/226478.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/4966.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/375018.png',
'http://images.sportinglife.com/racing/tsilks/17484.png',
]

root = tk.Tk()

for url in data:

    with urllib.request.urlopen(url) as u:
        raw_data = u.read()

    image = Image.open(BytesIO(raw_data))
    photo = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image)

    label = tk.Label(root, image=photo)
    label.photo = photo
    label.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

---

BTW: normally there is problem with `PhotoImage` when you create it in function or class but maybe there is the same problem inside `for` loop.

http://effbot.org/tkinterbook/photoimage.htm

Comment: Thank you, this works. What's the difference between image.im and label.im? And what is .im?

Comment: in `image.im = image` you assign `PhotoImage` to variable inside  the same `PhotoImage`. There is some bug and `garbage collector` sometimes destroys `PhotoImage` - so it destroys `image` and automaticaly it will destroy `image.im`  too (because it is part of `image`). `im` is your own variable - you can use any name. I use `photo`. If you assign to `label.im` or any variable in `non-PhotoImage` object then it doesn't destroy `label.im`.